# Add information to HTTP Header in WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, http-api

I am working on developing a plugin for a tool called Supportify. It is a REST API that is authenticated through a key and token added to the HTTP header of a HTTP request to their servers. Their API reference is [here](http://supportify.io/docs/api-reference/69/basic-overview). I know you can add things to the header with `wp-config.php` but for a publicly released plugin this is not feasible. Is there any way to do this through a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP allows you to send header information using the [`header()`](http://php.net/header/) command.

More specific to WordPress is the [`send_headers`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers) action hook.

Also: always remember that you have to send all your headers *before* any output is sent to the screen.